# if statement in java + Calculate the total

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a problem here when I write this example in java:

```
if ( deadline==1){ 
    total = A + B + C;
    System.out.println(" you get =" + total);
}
if ( deadline==2 ){ 
    total = A + B + C;
    Punishment = total*(5\100);
    Final = total - Punishment;
    System.out.println(" you get =" + Final);
}
```

And when I run it,
I write on the black screen the deadline =2
but it shows on the black screen ( you get = total)

To be clear that I have values of ( A , B , C). I write it before `if` statement + I ask the user before to write the number of the deadline using `Scanner`.

Comment: Please provide a complete example demonstrating the problem.  We can't just take your word for it that everything you did before the `if` statement must be correct and that `if` itself is broken in Java.

Comment: see, for example [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/153588480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, if both operands of an operation are integers, the operation is done as an integer operation.

Your code is doing `Punishment = total*(5\100)` - here the division is done as an integer operation, that is, the result of `(5*100)` is `0` (zero) and so `Punishment` will be zero too.

Option 1: change it to `Punishment = (total * 5) \ 100` so the multiplication is done first (parenthesis not needed).

Option 2: use double like `Punishment = (int)(total * (5.0\100))`

Option 3: also change the variable to double:

```
double punishment;
...
punishment = total * 5.0 / 100.0;
```

Note: variable names should start with lowercase letter by convention

<sup>assuming that `deadline` is `2`</sup>

Comment: I used the third option and it works, thanks